# Irwin - Hall distribution of n different uniform distributions $U_k(a_k,b_k)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given $n$ independent and identically distributed uniform distributions $U(0,1)$, their sum is:
$$X=\sum_{k=1}^nU_k(0,1)$$
The $pdf$ of this sum is given by the well known Irwin - Hall distribution.
What is the equivalent of the Irwin - Hall distribution if we have $n$ different $U_k(a_k,b_k)$? For example, we could have two distributions in which $U_1$ and $U_2$ are: $U_1=U(-1,1)$ and $U_2=U_2\left(-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$. What happens in this case? Thanks.

Comment: No direct answer, but my first impulse is writing it as $a+\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}U_k\left(0,1\right)$ where $c_{k}=b_{k}-a_{k}$
and $a=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74039/can-we-make-the-irwin-hall-distribution-more-general Summary: Except when $b_k-a_k$ does not depend on $k$, not much can be said.

Comment: Maybe first extend Irwin Hall to Unif$(a,b)$ from Unif$(0,1)$ and then extend to Unif$(a_k,b_k)$?